# click on label doesn't open select

Tags: html, forms, select, label

I always thought, that a click on a `label` will more or less "trigger" the click on the according form-element.
However this doesn't seem to work when it comes to `select`. The "mousedown-on-selectfield"-animation works but the select is not opening.

I tried this:

```
<label for="my_id">Click me</label>
<select id="my_id">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

and that:

```
<label for="my_id">Click me
  <select id="my_id">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

PS: Imo there should be no need for any Javascript here since this is an html-feature

Comment: On clicking on label,it will just focus the selectfield ,it will not open it

Comment: So why a checkbox is getting checked, when clicking on its label instead of only focusing it?

Comment: this how it works not possible without using javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per W3C, clicking on a label might do nothing or send onFocus event to the related field. In this case, normally it will trigger onFocus on the select element.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element
[image: label click]